# Inheritance : Unexpected Output from return statement

Tags: java, inheritance

I am taking a practice test for Java certification and got this question:

> What will the following code print?

```
class Baap {

    public int h = 4;

    public int getH() {
        System.out.println("Baap    "+h);
        return h;
    }  
}  

class Beta extends Baap {

    public int h = 44;

    public int getH() {
        System.out.println("Beta    " + h);
        return h;
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Baap b = new Beta();  
        System.out.println(b.h + "    " + b.getH());  
        Beta bb = (Beta) b;  
        System.out.println(bb.h + "   " + bb.getH());  
    }  
}
```

This is the answer:
Beta 44
**4** 44
Beta 44
44 44

My question: why is the **4** from the main class returned instead of the **44** from child class? Shouldn't it return 44?

I also don't see any variable that is shadowed by another variable with the same name that is closer in scope.

*(Sorry for my english. I am French speaking.)*

Comment: fields don't follow overriding.

Comment: a french speaking person writing Hindi classes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `Beta.h` and `Baap.h` are different fields. In `b.h`, `Baap.h` is called (which is 4) and `bb.h`, `Beta.h` is called (which is 44). The difference is that `b.getH()` calls `Beta.getH()` (because b is `new Beta()`) but is reading `Baap.h` field, while `bb.getH()` calls `Beta.getH()`.

Take a look at the `main()` method:

```
class Baap {  
    public int h = 4;  
    public int getH() { System.out.println("Baap    "+h); return h; }  
}  

class Beta extends Baap {
    public int h = 44;
    public int getH() { System.out.println("Beta    "+h); return h; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Baap b = new Beta();
        System.out.println(b.h + "    " + b.getH());
        /* The string concatenation gets compiled to:
         * new StringBuffer().append(b.h).append("    ").append(b.getH()).toString();
         *                             \ This is Baap.h         \ This prints Beta 44 and returns 44 from Beta.h
         */
        // Printed "Beta 44" from b.getH().
        // Printed "4    44" from statements concatenation.
        Beta bb = (Beta) b;  
        System.out.println(bb.h + "   " + bb.getH());
        /* The string concatenation gets compiled to:
         * new StringBuffer().append(bb.h).append("    ").append(bb.getH()).toString();
         *                             \ This is Beta.h          \ This prints Beta 44 and returns 44 from Beta.h
         */
        // Printed "Beta 44" from b.getH().
        // Printed "44    44" from statements concatenation.
    }
}
```

> From the [Oracle JavaTM Tutorials - Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html), it was written that:
>
> #### What You Can Do in a Subclass
>
> - The inherited fields can be used directly, just like any other fields.
> - You can declare a field in the subclass with the same name as the one in the superclass, thus hiding it (not recommended).
> - You can write a new instance method in the subclass that has the same signature as the one in the superclass, thus overriding it.
> - You can declare new fields in the subclass that are not in the superclass.

Read more:

- [why can we reduce visibility of a property in extended class in java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24719892/3622940)

Answer (score 2):

So your question is why `b.h` evaluates to `4` and not `44` in the following:

```
    Baap b = new Beta();  
    System.out.println(b.h + "    " + b.getH());  
                       ^^^ why is this 4?
```

The reason is that there is no data polymorphism in Java. Even though they share the same name, `Baap.h` and `Beta.h` are separate, unrelated fields.

When the compiler is resolving `b.h` it looks at the static (i.e. compile-time) type of `b`, not its dynamic (i.e. runtime) type.

The static type of `b` is `Baap`, so `b.h` resolves to `Baap.h`, which is `4`.

Comment: So the return h; statement is the last to be processed in the sequence. I thought it was the second to be processed right after the b.getH(); method call. Super thank you

Comment: @Rahoul: Yes, the fact that `getH()` is both getting called in a `println()` and using `println()` confuses things.

Comment: In the System.out.println(b.h + "    " + b.getH()) statement, I was expecting "b.h" to be printed first since it's the first member of the println statement, but it didn't. Could you tell me why's that?