# Java: Class extends class with static var, overwriting it - doesn't work - why?

Tags: java

I wrote something like this:

```
public abstract class A {
    static String name = "A";

    public static String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    static String name = "B";
}

public class C extends A {
    static String name = "C";
}
```

When I call `B b = new B(); System.out.println(b.getName());` (better of course `System.out.println(B.getName());`) I get A, not B (same for C).

I don't get why. Can someone give me a handwave?

---

Thanks for the answer!

But how would I do something like that?

In my case I want to make a URL Manager. The variable contains a Pattern, the method tests for a given String, if the Pattern matches.

Every class extending A has to have the Pattern and uses the same Method to test if it matches. It should be static too, because I only want to instantiate, if the Pattern matches.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719880/why-can-we-reduce-visibility-of-a-property-in-extended-class/24719892#24719892

Answer (score 4):

There is no polymorphism for static members and no polymorphism of data members. Polymorphism exists only for instance (non-static) methods. Your static `getName()` method is defined in `A` and returns the value of the static member defined in A.

Anyway, you shouldn't access static methods via an instance, since it's confusing. Use `A.getName()`.

Comment: +1 for pointing out avoiding accessing static methods via instances. Most IDEs also warns about this.

Comment: Yeah, totally right. Was too fast to abstract my actual code.